# Process.start not working on server

Tags: asp.net, c#-4.0, itext

I create a PDF file using itextsharp. It's created successfully and open with adobe reader 9 not in adobe reader 7 and 8. Please help me to fix this error.

This is my partial code :

```
      try
    {
        //yourFont = BaseFont.CreateFont(Application.StartupPath + "/verdana.TTF", BaseFont.WINANSI, BaseFont.EMBEDDED);
        pgSize = new iTextSharp.text.Rectangle(320, 455);

        doc = new Document(pgSize, 15, 5, 12, 4);
        fnt = new iTextSharp.text.Font(yourFont, 7, 3);
        fnt1 = new iTextSharp.text.Font(yourFont, 5, 0);
        fnt2 = new iTextSharp.text.Font(yourFont, 3, 2);
        fnt3 = new iTextSharp.text.Font(yourFont, 4, 6);


        PdfWriter.GetInstance(doc, new FileStream(Server.MapPath("Payslip.pdf"), FileMode.Create));
        //PdfWriter.GetInstance(doc, new FileStream(Server.MapPath("Payslip.pdf"), FileMode.Create)); //Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.Desktop) + "\\Payslip.pdf"

        doc.Open();
        DataView DView = (DataView)Session["data_value"];
        dtData = DView.ToTable();
        dr = dtData.Select("fldemp_no='" + Session["EmployeeID"].ToString() + "'");
        doc.NewPage();
        iTextSharp.text.Image ObjImg = iTextSharp.text.Image.GetInstance(Server.MapPath("~/Bin/Head.png"));
        ObjImg.Alignment = iTextSharp.text.Image.ALIGN_CENTER;
        ObjImg.ScaleToFit(220f, 150f);
        ObjImg.SpacingBefore = 13f;
        ObjImg.SpacingAfter = 1f;
        doc.Add(ObjImg);

        maintable = new PdfPTable(1);
        cell = new PdfPCell(new Phrase("Pay Slip for the month of " + dr[0]["fldmonth"].ToString(), fnt1));
        cell.HorizontalAlignment = Element.ALIGN_CENTER;
        cell.Border = 0;
        maintable.AddCell(cell);
        doc.Add(maintable);

        maintable = new PdfPTable(2);
        empdetright = new PdfPTable(2);

        empdetleft = new PdfPTable(2);
        cell = new PdfPCell(new Phrase("Emp No", fnt1));
        cell.Border = 0;
        empdetright.AddCell(cell);

        cell = new PdfPCell(new Phrase(": " + dr[0]["fldemp_no"].ToString(), fnt1));
        cell.Border = 0;
        empdetright.AddCell(cell);

        cell = new PdfPCell(new Phrase("Emp Name", fnt1));
        cell.Border = 0;
        empdetright.AddCell(cell);
        cell = new PdfPCell(new Phrase(": " + dr[0]["fldempname"].ToString(), fnt1));
        cell.Border = 0;
        empdetright.AddCell(cell);

        .......

         doc.Close();

        Process.Start(Server.MapPath("Payslip.pdf"));
```

The above code is run on local machine not on server. Please help me to fix this error..

Comment: The title appears to be unrelated to the issue you have, which seems to be that you have generated a PDF via iTextSharp but it will only open in Reader 9, not Reader 7 or 8. Is this correct?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Process.Start` will attempt to open the file in the computer it is running (the server).

This is unlikely to be what you want. You should be uploading the file to the browser and let it decide (using `Response.WriteFile`, for instance).

Comment: @Amulraj - What error? Same as what? You didn't specify errors in your question or in the comment.

Comment: There was a problem reading this document(117) and There was an error opening this document.

Comment: @Amulraj - Then the document generated was probably not a valid PDF.

Comment: But it's opening in Adobe 9 .

Comment: @Amulraj - Where are you getting the error? How are you trying to open the file?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/13160/discussion-between-amulraj-and-oded)